# При смене ориентации экрана на iphone XR и выше ломаются стили

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

Столкнулся с проблемой что, при смене ориентации на айфоне XR и 11PRO ломаются шрифты. Сайт вот этот: http://centr.fase-app.ru/. Повторить проблему через десктоп браузеры не удается, только на этих устройствах. Закономерности в поломке не обнаружил, 1 из 2-х блоков может сломаться, с одинаковыми стилями

Answer (score 1):

Вот решение: в начало стилей:

```
body{
   -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}
```

Comment: Используй `reset.css` или `normalize.css` дабы избежать подобных проблем в будущем